# PSSH private key issue

Tags: python, paramiko, pssh

I'm new to PSSH. I followed the PSSH document to write the script. When I use Private key, it returns with the error "ImportError: No module named ecdsakey"
I tried downloading that module but there is no "ecdsakey" modul,the module available is "ecdsa" and it's already installed. Searched everywhere but couldn't find the relevant answer.I'm using ubuntu14.04 OS

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pprint import pprint
import paramiko
from pssh.pssh_client import ParallelSSHClient
from pssh.exceptions import AuthenticationException,UnknownHostException,ConnectionErrorException
client_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/pssh.txt')
client=ParallelSSHClient(['ip1','ip2'],pkey=client_key)
try:
    output=client.run_command('ls /',sudo=True)
except(AuthenticationException,UnknownHostException,ConnectionErrorException):
    pass
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pssh1.py", line 4, in <module>
from pssh.utils import load_private_key
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pssh/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
from .pssh_client import ParallelSSHClient
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pssh/pssh_client.py", line 36, in <module>
from .ssh_client import SSHClient
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pssh/ssh_client.py", line 32, in <module>
from .utils import read_openssh_config
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pssh/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
from paramiko.ecdsakey import ECDSAKey
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named ecdsakey
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
sudo pip install ecdsa
```

If you are on Python 3.x you might have to use pip3 instead of pip:

```
sudo pip3 install ecdsa
```